# pip.conf not paying attention to trusted-host

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I have my `pip.conf` file as follows:

```
[global]
trusted-host = <private IP>
extra-index-url = http://<private IP>/pypi
```

However, whenever I try to install a package (just a test package) from the private pypi repo, I receive an error that instructs me to add `--trusted-host <private IP>`.  If I do, I can successfully install the package, so I know that `pip` is reading the `pip.conf` file.  Why isn't it respecting the `trusted-host` config?  I've triple checked that the IPs match in the config file.

Several blogs and cursory searches of Google seem to suggest that it should.  (https://pseudoscripter.wordpress.com/2016/05/07/pip-the-repository-located-at-some-ip-is-not-a-trusted-or-secure-host-and-is-being-ignored/)

Comment: For troubleshooting, you should first try specifying the path to your `pip.conf` explicitly with the `PIP_CONFIG_FILE` environment variable. If that works, then it is just a precedence related problem. Also examine `pip config list`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Couldn't this be a problem of different pip.conf having different configurations?According to the [official docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file):

The names and locations of the configuration files vary slightly across platforms. You may have per-user, per-virtualenv or site-wide (shared amongst all users) configuration.

- On Unix the default configuration file *is: $HOME/.config/pip/pip.conf* which respects the *XDG_CONFIG_HOME* environment variable.
- There is also a legacy per-user configuration file which is also respected, and is located at  *$HOME/.pip/pip.conf* on Unix and macOS.
- Inside a virtualenv, on Unix and macOS the file is *$VIRTUAL_ENV/pip.conf*
- Site-wide, on Unix the file may be located in */etc/pip.conf*. Alternatively it may be in a "pip" subdirectory of any of the paths set in the environment variable *XDG_CONFIG_DIRS* (if it exists), for example */etc/xdg/pip/pip.conf*.

Comment: For `trusted-host`, can that be a comma-separated list?

Answer (score 2):

Copied my pip.conf from $HOME/.pip/pip.conf to /etc/pip.conf and it worked!

Comment: hi i did the same thing but no luck, did you put it in the same section `[global]` ?
i put both the `proxy` and `trusted-host` configs in this file. and pip is clearly taking the `proxy` config but ignoring `trusted-host`

Comment: @Mheni No, I put it under its own section, not under `[global]`.

Answer (score 1):

To check which config file is being looked at run: `pip config --editor pathtoeditorofyourchoice edit`, this will open the linked ini file. If it doesnt exist, the Editor (notepad++) will state that there is no file at a specific path <-- and there is your path where you should place the file then.

Also consider as stated here (https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide):

> If multiple configuration files are found by pip then they are
>   combined in the following order:
>
> ```
> The site-wide file is read
> The per-user file is read
> The virtualenv-specific file is read
> ```
>
> Each file read overrides any values read from previous files, so if
>   the global timeout is specified in both the site-wide file and the
>   per-user file then the latter value will be used.

The docs also say:

> You can set a custom path location for this config file using the
>   environment variable PIP_CONFIG_FILE.

However, running the upper command with this environment variable set up lead to a

```
Fatal Internal error [id=2]. Please report as a bug.
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be using an old version of PIP. Try upgrading using:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```