# Specifying multiple trusted hosts in pip.conf

Tags: python, configuration, pip

This is what I tried setting in my `/etc/pip.conf`:

```
[global]
trusted-host = pypi.org, files.pythonhosted.org
```

However, it is not working properly.

References:

- https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_config
- https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip/#cmdoption-trusted-host

See also: [pip.conf not paying attention to trusted-host](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45337029)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Space-separated, not comma-separated:

```
[global]
trusted-host = pypi.org files.pythonhosted.org
```

or

```
[global]
trusted-host = pypi.org
               files.pythonhosted.org
```

Comment: Can you provide a reference for future use? Also, how would I do that via `pip config set`?

Comment: I just stole it as an example from https://stackoverflow.com/a/52054867/7976758. `pip config set global.trusted-host="pypi.org files.pythonhosted.org"`, I suppose.

Comment: @phd `pip config set [name] [value]` should be used, the `=` sign should be  removed.

Comment: @GaryWang Yep, you're right, my bad, thanks for spotting! Too late to edit the comment so here is the fixed version: `pip config set global.trusted-host "pypi.org files.pythonhosted.org"`

Answer (score 20):

This worked for me using the command line, Python 3.9.1, pip 20.2.3, & a virtual environment. No equals sign after "global.trusted-host".

```
pip config set global.trusted-host "pypi.org files.pythonhosted.org pypi.python.org"
```

Motivation: I don't want to disconnect from a VPN or specify --trusted-host each time I install a package.

```
pip config list
```

Produces the following:

```
global.trusted-host='pypi.org files.pythonhosted.org pypi.python.org'
```

DID NOT work:

```
pip config set global.trusted-host="pypi.org files.pythonhosted.org pypi.python.org"

ERROR: Got unexpected number of arguments, expected 2. (example: "pip config set [name] [value]")
```

Comment: Upvoted. Easy to put in Dockerfile in case build is happening with SSL interception (proxy)

Comment: Thanks...this worked,  no equals sign!

Answer (score 14):

To do from the command line
`python -m pip config set global.trusted-host=pypi.org files.pythonhosted.org`

Answer (score 3):

If you are facing following issue while using **pip install application_name**:

**Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url**

***The following solution will help solve the problem:-***
First find the pip location. For this you can run the following command-

```
pip config -v list
```

The default recommended location for pip creation is:

```
C:\Users\your_username_here\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.ini
```

You need to append the following lines **manually**-

```
[global]
trusted-host = pypi.org files.pythonhosted.org
```

Instead of manually creating the pip.ini file at the above location, please run the following command line prompt-

```
python -m pip config set global.trusted-host=pypi.org files.pythonhosted.org
```

Remember it takes only 2 locations to be trusted. If you provide the 3rd one, then it will throw an error. Once successful, it will create the pip.ini file at the above location automatically and it is better than manual steps.

After this commands like the following should work without an error-

```
pip install virtualenv
```

I have tried the above steps in Windows 10 home edition and it worked for me.

Hope this summary helps!

Comment: Thanks bud much easier than typing the trusted host lines with every call to pip on my corporate PC.